# How do I return an iterator that has a reference to something inside a RefCell?

Tags: reference, rust, iterator, interior-mutability

I'm trying to create a method that returns an iterator over the values of `HashMap` that is boxed inside a `RefCell`, but i'm having an error where `Ref` returned by `RefCell::borrow`  doesn't live long enough for iterator to be returned from the method. Here's my code:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Values;

struct Foo {
    map: Rc<RefCell<HashMap<i32, i32>>>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn iter(&self) -> Values<i32, i32> {
        self.map.borrow().values()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        map: Rc::new(RefCell::new(HashMap::new()))
    };

    for v in foo.iter() {
        println!("{}", v)
    }
}
```

Compilation error:

```
rustc 1.15.1 (021bd294c 2017-02-08)
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:12:9
   |
12 |         self.map.borrow().values()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
13 |     }
   |     - temporary value only lives until here
   |
```

[How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401626/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-something-inside-a-refcell-without-breaking-encap) suggests creating a guard that incapsulates `Ref` and provides an interface for accessing the underlying value, but what I need to do is to return an iterator object (`Values<'a, K, V>`) that already incapsulates a plain reference to a `HashMap`.

My main problem is that I have a runtime tracked reference `Ref<T>` while I need a plain reference to create an iterator. `Ref::map` exposes a plain reference for mapping, but it requires the mapper function to return another reference which is impossible here. Should I redo the entire iterator functionality to work with `Ref` or is there a better way?

Comment: Related: [Returning the T borrowed from RefCell<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30281664/155423)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this.

The ultimate problem is that `std::collections::hash_map::Values` holds a reference, but you don't have "just" a reference. You have the smart pointer `Ref`.

The easiest solution I know of is to invert the code:

```
impl Foo {
    fn with_iter<F, T>(&self, f: F) -> T
    where
        F: FnOnce(Values<i32, i32>) -> T,
    {
        f(self.map.borrow().values())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        map: Rc::new(RefCell::new(HashMap::new())),
    };

    foo.with_iter(|i| {
        for v in i {
            println!("{}", v)
        }
    })
}
```

Here, the `Values` iterator no longer needs to outlive the result of `borrow`, so there's no additional complexity.

If you are OK with leaking your implementation, you can return the `Ref`:

```
impl Foo {
    fn iter(&self) -> Ref<'_, HashMap<i32, i32>> {
        self.map.borrow()
    }
}
```

```
for v in foo.iter().values() {
    println!("{}", v)
}
```

In newer versions of Rust, you can return an unnamed type that implements `Deref`:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

impl Foo {
    fn iter(&self) -> impl Deref<Target = HashMap<i32, i32>> + '_ {
        self.map.borrow()
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29401626/155423)

Comment: (You can probably do this with `unsafe` code, but my brain isn't showing me the way at the moment).

Comment: With [`RefCell::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.as_ptr), perhaps?

Comment: Wait, no... you'd also have to fiddle with the contents of the `RefCell` to make sure nobody else borrowed it as mutable while the `Values` existed. Tricksy