# How can I create an Iter over a Vec contained in a RefCell?

Tags: rust

I cannot figure out why the following will not compile:

```
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};
use std::slice::Iter;

struct Vector {
    data: RefCell<Vec<f64>>,
}

impl Vector {
    pub fn new(data: Vec<f64>) -> Self {
        Vector {data: RefCell::new(data)}
    }

    pub fn get_data(&self) -> Ref<Vec<f64>> {
        self.data.borrow()
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<f64> {
        self.get_data().iter()
        // Fails with `self.get_data()` does not live long enough
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Acell%3A%3A%7BRefCell%2C%20Ref%7D%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aslice%3A%3AIter%3B%0A%0Astruct%20Vector%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20RefCell%3CVec%3Cf64%3E%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Vector%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20new(data%3A%20Vec%3Cf64%3E)%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Vector%20%7Bdata%3A%20RefCell%3A%3Anew(data)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20get_data(%26self)%20-%3E%20Ref%3CVec%3Cf64%3E%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.data.borrow()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20iter(%26self)%20-%3E%20Iter%3Cf64%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.get_data().iter()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fails%20with%20%60self.get_data()%60%20does%20not%20live%20long%20enough%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)

The full error is:

```
rustc 1.16.0 (30cf806ef 2017-03-10)
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:18:9
   |
18 |         self.get_data().iter()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
19 |         // Fails with `self.get_data()` does not live long enough
20 |     }
   |     - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 17:36...
  --> <anon>:17:37
   |
17 |       pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<f64> {
   |  _____________________________________^ starting here...
18 | |         self.get_data().iter()
19 | |         // Fails with `self.get_data()` does not live long enough
20 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: Have you already seen [Returning the T borrowed from RefCell<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30281664/155423)?

Comment: I have, but I cannot figure out how to properly apply that to my situation. I tried to define `data` at `RefCell<Rc<Vec<f64>>>`, but how will I get an `Iter` out of that? @Shepmaster